# Best way to social authenticate a Vue-cli SPA with AdonisJS on de backend

Tags: vue.js, single-page-application, adonis.js, social-authentication

I'm a huge fan of Vue and I recently discovered AdonisJs and since I come from Laravel I instantly fallen in love with it. That being said I was trying to start a project where I could login with github (or google or facebook...) in the SPA and then use the token given by the Social Authentication to authenticate (JWT) my requests on the AdonisJs side.

I tried with firebase init in the SPA project, but I don't know if it is secure enough to use the accessToken given by firebase as a JWT for my backend.

Then I tried AdonisJS Social Authentication method [AdonisJS Social Authentication](https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/auth/social) but failed to implement it as it seems the only option is via web/session guard, since it's all based on redirects.

Do you guys know which path should I take? Is there a better way to do this maybe?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find out if Adonis supports this?